# Different ways to program a recursive algorithm

Tags: functional-style, code-request

Construct `f` (a numeric function) which takes multiple arguments with the following property:

The single argument case $f(x_1)$ is meaningless, and the two-argument function $f(x_1,x_2)$ is the base case.  The multivariable function $f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,\ldots)$ is determined from those with fewer arguments as follows:

$$f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) = f(x_1 x_2 \ldots x_{n-1}, x_n) + f(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$$

Here are some examples of the expected output:

```
f[a, b, c]
(*  f[a, b] + f[a b, c]  *)

f[a, b, c, d, e]
(*  f[a, b] + f[a b, c] + f[a b c, d] + f[a b c d, e]  *)
```

Here is my (recursive) implementation:

```
f[args : PatternSequence[_, __], last_] := f[Times[args], last] + f[args]
```

Are there other ways the implement this in *Mathematica*?  How about using iteration?  Can it be done using recursive pure functions?

Comment: `If[Length[{##}] > 2, #0[Times @@ Most[{##}], Last[{##}]] + #0 @@ Most[{##}], f[##]] &[a, b, c, d, e]`?

Comment: `Total[NestList[Most, f[a, b, c, d], 2]]` will probably be faster.

Comment: @C.E. the appropriate arguments are not multiplied altogether in that case, tho. The replacement rule `f[args__, last_] :> f[Times[args], last]` will of course take care of that.

Comment: @J.M. That's true, I misread.